# Notorious Visual Studio Error C1902, VS configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am getting the notorious "Error C1902: Program database manager mismatch; please check your installation" in my VC++ builds in Visual Studio 2010. My VS will not even build hello world, there is no pdb file even in existence in the folder.

Steps I have tried:

- cleaning and rebuilding (3 different projects including hello world, about 15 times)
- removing every single instance of Visual Studio before version 2010 from the computer including all redistributables. There is no copy of mspdb*.dll on my computer anywhere except the latest version (100) in my 2010 directory.
- Reinstalling 2010. I completely reinstalled VS 2010. No effect.
- Rebooting my computer. I have spent the afternoon deleting anything that might be remotely related to this bug and rebooting over and over again.

Comment: I ran into this issue when running `MSBuild.exe` under cygwin sshd with public key authentication. This can be solved by [fixing the impersonation](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-nopasswd2)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I solved the problem by finding an obscure post to a similar thread created a couple of years ago on a different forum. Here is the solution:

Copy the file mspdbsrv.exe from the VisualStudio/Common7/IDE directory to the /VC/bin directory.

Comment: +++++ It seems MS scoffs developers. I wasted days to find fix of this issue after misterious appearing of it. And after one more couple of years you post appears still actual. It seems issue appeared after automatic windows update http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2565063 , but I am not sure

Comment: May the Force be with you!

Comment: The correct filename is mspdbsrv.exe NOT mspdbsvr.exe!  For those using filename searches. [The R,V are transposed]

Comment: I also had to copy mspdbcore.dll and msobj80.dll from and to the same folders.

Comment: Why it is deleted at first place ? Till yesterday my code was working

Answer (score 1):

`cyglas-config` solved the problem on my build system. Is seems that Vs2010+ needs this but vs2008 didnt.

Comment: FWLIW -- I feel like this is the more contemporary answer.  Lots of false starts in 2015 with the file removal related hints.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this caused by two projects sharing an intermediate directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make your your VS2010 is running under administrator and have the right permission.

Our IT deployed a tool for blocking access to several "ports", it turned out all my VC project cannot build in VS2010. He then re-deployed the tool with "allow elevated program access blocked 'ports'" checked and everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Verify local user account if ran under automation is not locked. this turned out to be a resolution for issue I had seen with "fatal error C1902: Program database manager mismatch; please check your installation" message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and the problem was that the "mspdbcore.dll" file was deleted from my \Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\ folder. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7hea02.aspx) post helped me solving my issue.

PS:The deletion was made by a "duplicate files cleaner" utility.