# How to install one version of visual studio 2013 with c++ 2010, 2012 and 2013 toolsets

Tags: c++, visual-studio

How can I install visual studio 2013 with c++ 2010, 2012 and 2013 toolsets without installing any other visual studio versions (express or any other versions).

I need this so that I can keep my pc light and clean. Are there any alternatives to installing multiple visual studio versions for c++ toolsets?

I am developing a plugin for a program that has multiple version each compiled in c++ 2010 and c++ 2012 so I need those version of c++ toolset. For daily use I need visual studio 2013.

Comment: `I need this so that I can keep my pc light and clean` Get a larger hard drive. AFAIK, you must install those versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to build with v90 platform toolset in VS2012 without VS2008, using Windows SDK?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24775363/how-to-build-with-v90-platform-toolset-in-vs2012-without-vs2008-using-windows-s)

Comment: If this is just a temporary need, you can use a virtual machine, and pollute that with all the old VS versions, while keeping your host environment clean. (In my experience, installing VS2010 after 2013 produced some quirks that I'd avoid if I had the choice.)

Answer (score 1):

In the end I installed the express editions that use around 800mb each and do not add so much clutter.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN's website says that if you want the C++ 2010 and C++ 2012 toolsets with VS2013, you'll need to install those VS versions on that particular machine. Link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh690665.aspx)

I don't think there are other alternatives to that.